# base64_encode apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, base64

Everytime I base64_encode(); new data in my database and it contains apostrophes ('), my text comes out like this when I base64_decode it:

Original: Hi! **Where's** everyone?

After Encryption: Hi! **Where/'s** everyone?

How do I stop this with PHP?

Comment: Apply stripslashes() before decoding?

Comment: It's not encryption, but the way. [Read more about Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: I don't think base64 is doing this. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Tim Cooper it's an encryption technique.

Comment: @yanike no, it's an *encoding* technique

Comment: @yanike - base64 encoded text might as well be _plain text_ (hence the reason why the implementation ends in `_encode()`). A few rather experienced people are trying to tell you something :) `base64_encode()` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: ok. I listed. All I know is that it does what I need. Also, again -3 for asking a question. Anyways, I got what I needed.

Comment: Please don't take it the wrong way. I do listen and I will look more into encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stripslashes()` on the decoded output, but make sure that it was properly escaped before being inserted into the database to begin with.  Are you encoding and decoding it both with PHP?

Comment: Thanks that worked on encoding and decoding it. Headache avoided. Thanks to everyone else as well for your help. I'll take note for future use.

Comment: @yanike no, you choose wrong word. Nothing has been avoided but rather increased. You guys always cure symptom, not the cause.

Comment: How do you turn this "&#039;" into "'" when exporting.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with `magic_quotes` being on.

Am I correct to suppose that you `base64_encode` data coming from a form and saving it to the database?

If so, define and use this function to process anything that comes from `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`:

```
function escape_gpc($var) {
    return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($var) : $var;
}

if (isset($_POST['form_sent'])) {
    $somedata = escape_gpc($_POST['somedata']);
    // and then you base64_encode it and insert into the database.
}
```

Comment: Still, I highly recommend just _disabling_ magic quotes when you find them enabled. They cause a considerable amount of problems.

Comment: I doubt it's not magic quotes. Most likely the OP just escaping his data manually, because it's "safe".

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of base64 encoding and you'll be fine.
Do not encode before insert.
Do not decode when retrieve.

That's all.

Look, your case is all clear.

- First, you are escaping your data, by adding backslashes to the several characters.
  That's enough for the strings, enclosed in the query in quotes. No more encoding needed ever!
  These backslashes should go off then data got inserted, so, you get your data untouched in the database.
- Next, you're encoding your strings, **sealing slashes within!**
  Then, after decoding, you have a backslash in your data.

So, you have just to get rid of base64, and everything will be okay at once!

Comment: No. That's very unsafe. That's the reason why I encode things.

Comment: @yanike listen, pal. There are tens of thousands programmers on this site. NONE of them doing base64 encoding. Because it adds no safety but headache only. You are escaping your data - that's enough.

Comment: @yanike: Really. I'd like to find out what that reason is. Parameterized queries and `mysql_real_escape_string` are there for a reason.

Comment: @yanike - Col. Shrapnel is correct. base64 encoding has its uses, but what you are using it for is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using some escaping function (I suppose mysql_real_escape_string, but just out of statistics, you didn't mention if you're using a DB over the other or prepared statements), chances are you have magic_quotes_gpc directive on in php.ini, so escaping backslashes are added automatically before inserting datas into DB.
So, when retrieving records, you'll have the backslash. Encoding/decoding is just what it's supposed to be: encoding and decoding a string.

use `$decoded = stripslashes(base_64decode($your_datas_from_db));`

Comment: it should be used at least opposite. there is no point in using stripslashes on base64 encoded data. And there is no point in using base64 at all.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Agree on that, but since I don't know why OP wants to encode strings (at least at the time of answering), I thought it was the best thing to tell what was wrong in his code and how to correct it from there, not rewriting all his code to how best i should've been in my opinion. I watched your very recent war against this kind of answers and I must say you have a point there; I liked the "you cure symptoms not cause' motto, I'll make sure to stick it into my mind for the future, thanks man

Comment: thanks for your support. But still you have to at least reverse base_64decode and stripslashes usage, or you won't get desired effect.